# Allocating variable names when unpickling dynamically

Tags: python, pickle

Regarding python pickle:
I have a situation where I am trying to reload a bunch of variables that I have saved off to files that I have named the original variable names + .pkl

I can reload the data, but cannot find a simple way to translate this data back to their original names. Here's my code:

```
varsToPickle=('gradBoostersIN',
              'gradBoostersOUT',
              'gradBoostersSTAT',
              'predictTableTest',
              'predictTableTrain',
              'scoresTrainIN',
              'scoresTrainOUT',
              'scoresTrainSTAT',
              'scoresTestIN',
              'scoresTestOUT',
              'scoresTestSTAT')

for fn in varsToPickle:

    var_filename = '(A_Pathway)/%s.pkl' %fn
    # Open the file to load the var
    var_pkl = open(var_filename, 'rb')
    pickle.load(var_pkl)
    # this is where id like to have the load assign the output to variable fn
    # something like:    eval('%s = pickle.load(var_pkl)' %fn)
    # Close the pickle instances
    var_pkl.close()
```

I'm new to python, but I really don't like this method for a number of reasons (not least of which is eval() scares me). I feel like this has to be something that is done regularly, but I cannot find the right way to search for this answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Individually pickling a bunch of random variables into separate files seems like a poor design.  Put them all in a single object of some sort (a dictionary, if nothing more suitable comes to mind), and you can deal with all of them at one shot.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the suggestion. This should've been obvious to me before starting down the road of running long scripts without a gameplan for how to store their output coherently first. Cheers!